# Unknown class SKView in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios7, ios6, sprite-kit, skview

i changed the target for my App from iOS 7.0 to 6.0 and now i get that error, when i start the iOS simulator. I search at google and tried all suggestions.

- Library Simulator cleaned.
- Targets - compile sources - all .m files added.
- iOS simulator resetted.
- all linked frameworks like sprite kit changed from required to optional.

But i got always the same error. What can I do?

Thanks for Answers and sorry for  my bad english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprite Kit is not supported on iOS 6.  You will have to change the target back to iOS 7.

Comment: [Apple’s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1) showing this.